# best way to import very large file

Tags: r, fread

[image]

The data can be found at https://www.bls.gov/cew/downloadable-data-files.htm. It is the single file found in the middle of the page. I opened up the zip file for the 2021 file and renamed the csv to just 2021 instead of 2021.q1-q4.singlefile. I tried opening it in notepad ++ but it says that it is too large. Also, can't open it in excel. I try the following code and get the error below. Is this error telling me that it is too large or can't read it? Also use the command, read.csv to no avail. Any suggestions? I thought of opening it in Notepad ++ and doing a save as 2021.txt

```
  msa2021 <-fread("S:/file_path/2021.csv") 

 Warning in (if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") system else shell)(paste0("(",  :
'(S:/file_path/2021.csv) > 
 C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Temp\3\RtmpqCvyUH\file2eac5c0526dd' execution failed with 
error code 1
Warning in fread("S:file_path/2021.csv") 
 :
 File 'C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Temp\3\RtmpqCvyUH\file2eac5c0526dd' has size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.
```

Comment: What do you mean " It is the single file found in the middle of the page."? Which link did you click on?  Maybe csv -> single files ?   But quarterly or yearly?

Comment: If you look at the file in your operating system, how big does it say it is? How much memory do you have? And did you unzip it first, or are you reading the zipped version?

Comment: You find it by scrolling down a bit and then look for CSV's Single Files. There are two columns; quarterly and annual averages. I chose Quarterly and then 2021.

Comment: @GregorThomas. It says  2,132,905 kb. How do I find out how much memory I have?

Comment: Looks like you're on Windows. I searched for "how much memory does my computer have" and got this: *Click on the Windows Start menu and type in System Information. A list of search results pops up, among which is the System Information utility. Click on it. Scroll down to Installed Physical Memory (RAM) and see how much memory is installed on your computer.*

Comment: @GregorThomas. 32.0 GB

Comment: I was able to download and read that file with no problem. My R process scaled from 60MB (starting state, empty global) to 5GB of committed memory on reading it (an imperfect measure), and `object.size(x)` returned `3,946,745,704 bytes` (commas added for clarity here). I'm on win11, using R-4.1.2 and data.table-1.14.2. I suggest that whatever problems you're having have nothing to do with `data.table::fread` or possibly even R. (The biggest unknown I have is the presence of `S:` in the code, perhaps copy to your `C:` drive before trying to read?)

Comment: (For clarity/specificity, I downloaded https://data.bls.gov/cew/data/files/2021/csv/2021_qtrly_singlefile.zip.)

Comment: @r2evans... The S: is just the name of the drive that I was using to import from.  I will try to do so from the C drive.

Comment: I'm familiar with windows and its drive nomenclature, I was saying that that's the only component I cannot reproduce; even when I connect to a network share, the parameters of the connection are almost certainly different than what you have, so it is a bit futile for me to try to replicate that. There are frequently problems in Windows trying to open files on network drives, frequently-enough that when something glitches like this, I generally try to open it locally to see if that's the (only) problem.

Comment: @r2evans. Feel free to write this up as an answer so that you can get credit. I download stuff from these network drives probably 25 times a day with no issue. Weird stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transcribed from comments:

Occasionally (too often?) I find problems loading files from network drives (perhaps more so reading from within R/python). In cases like this, try copying from the network drive `S:` to somewhere on your local `C:` drive and read from there. In this case, your problem has nothing to do with `data.table::fread` or the data size, merely a glitch accessing that large a file on the network.